# Write file from server returns success, but can not find file

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to do a simple fs.writeFile on this server in meteor. It returns a success message for the majority of solutions I have tried. But I cannot find the file anywhere in the file structure. Ideas?
Here is a simple snippet I have tried.

```
const fs = require('fs');

var path = process.env['METEOR_SHELL_DIR'] + '/../../../public';

fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error:" + err);
    } else {
        console.log("Success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of writing to `'helloworld.txt'`, perhaps you want to write to `path+'/helloworld.txt'`?

Comment: You are correct, if you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: It says I have to wait 10 mins. but then I will. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing to `'helloworld.txt'`, but I think you meant to write to `path+'/helloworld.txt'`.